# What does the use of the the use of dot operator in example of a SQL query do or mean?

Tags: sql

In this query, I don't get it:

What are `p1.Person` and `p2.Person`.

[image: This is the picture]

```
SELECT p1.Person AS PERSON, p2.Person AS FRIEND_OF_FRIEND
FROM PersonFriend pfl JOIN Person p1 ON pfl.PersonID = p1.ID
    JOIN PersonFriend pf2 ON pf2.PersonID = pf1.FriendID
    JOIN Person p2 ON pf2.FriendID = p2.ID
WHERE p1.Person = "Alice" AND pf2.FriendID <> p1.ID
```

Comment: Multiple references to the same table:  MSDN doco: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ethytz2x.aspx

Comment: @mcalex but where are p1 and p2 defined.

Comment: they're aliased in the From:  ' ... join Person **p1** ' like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias#198214

Answer (score 1):

As mcalex pointed out they are table references, in this case they're referencing the same table twice as it's joined to itself. The `Person` bit contains the Name of the person (according to the graphic).

The query is the following:

```
SELECT  p1.Person AS PERSON, p2.Person AS FRIEND_OF_FRIEND
FROM    PersonFriend pf1 
    JOIN Person p1 ON pf1.PersonID = p1.ID
    JOIN PersonFriend pf2 ON pf2.PersonID = pf1.FriendID
    JOIN Person p2 ON pf2.FriendID = p2.ID
WHERE   p1.Person = "Alice" and pf2.FriendID <> p1.ID
```

Carefully look at each mention of a table in the `FROM` clause. You will be able to see that at each mention there is a shorthand assigned (e.g. `JOIN Person`**`p1`**). You end up with the following shorthands/reference names: `p1`, `p2`, `pf1` and `pf2`. While `p1` and `p2` reference the table `Person`, `pf1` and `pf2` reference `PersonFriend`.

Under normal circumstances you could use the whole name of a table like `Person` or `PersonFriend` in the `JOINS` but as there are multiple self joins in this query you need another way to identify which fields of which specific instance of the tables you mean.

Edit: The reference given by mcalex ([Using a Table Twice in One Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ethytz2x.aspx)) has some more information about the meaning of a self join.